# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.withRouter) is not a function when navigating to route programmatically in react-router 2.4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am using `react-router 2.4.0` and want to link to another route programmatically (what I did before using `<Link>`).

It's explained nicely in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router) where they say in `2.4.x` you should use the decorator pattern with `withRouter`, so I am using the following code:

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router' // further imports omitted


class CreateJobItemFormRaw extends React.Component {
  ...
}

const CreateJobItemForm = withRouter(CreateJobItemFormRaw)
export default CreateJobItemForm
```

Then in other files, I use

```
import CreateJobItemForm from './CreateJobItemForm'
```

However, with this approach my app doesn't render at all any more and the console outputs:

```
CreateJobItemForm.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.withRouter) is not a function
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I trust that you are in fact using react-router 2.4.0, but in my case it was worth double-checking that my package.json did in fact enforce that version.  I modified my package.json as such:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react-router": "^2.4.0",
  ...
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Works for me, thx ! The `npm update` command wasn't enough, I had to uninstall react-router then make an `npm install react-router@2.8.1` to make it update.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I upgraded to react-router v6 and discovered that `withRouter` was removed and hooks should be used instead.

Upgrade documentation here:
https://reactrouter.com/en/main/upgrading/v5

> Along with the upgrade to v5.1, you should replace any usage of withRouter with hooks.

Here is a detailed guide to hooks:
https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/

Answer (score 0):

In a comment to another answer you linked to this question and said that you're trying to navigate using react-router 2.4+. Try and put the PropType specifications in the file and see if that gives you any warnings. For Example:

```
// PropTypes
Example.propTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }).isRequired
};
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! I did put in the `propTypes`, but the issue remains. the weird thing is that my whole app doesn't at all, even though initially the component that uses `withRouter` isn't even mounted...

Comment: Is there any chance that the bundle that's being served to the browser is out-of-date. i.e. the wrong one. I saw this sort of thing once where webpack was talking a long time to rebuild the bundle.js file and I had refreshed the browser and it picked up an old one.

You could put a `debugger;` statement in there and check what has been put onto `this.props` by react-router and see if it looks reasonable to you...

Comment: yay guys, if anyone gets this far, don't forget to restart webpack or rebundle :P it made it for me

Answer (score -1):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

react-router v4.x
```

Comment: I have this in v5 and it still doesn't fix the issue: `TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.withRouter) is not a function`

Comment: For it fixed my issue with the withRouter. So saying thanks.